# Return the DataRow where X value exists from DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataTable as follows:

```
OptionName  OptionValue

   'A'        100
   'B'        85
   'C'        75
   'D'        60
```

I need to set a label `'lblMark'` with the Text in OptionName where the Option value is 85 for example.

**EDIT:**

What I'm currently doing is that i use a dropdownlist whose datasource is set to the DataTable above and i set the selected value to the value i want. This way i would get the name.

However i'm in a case where i do not want to display a dropdownlist

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using linq it's easy

```
lblMark.Text=dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dr=>Convert.ToInt32(dr["OptionValue"])==85).First()["OptionName "].ToString();
```

Notice that if there's no matches , you'll get an exception.

Safer code :

```
List<DataRow> lst =dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dr=>Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"])==5).ToList();
   if(lst.Count==1)
   {
    lblMark.Text = lst[0]["OptionName"].ToString();
   }
```

or

```
var lst =dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dr=>Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"])==5).SingleOrDefault();
   if(lst!=null)
   {
    lblMark.Text = lst[0]["OptionName"].ToString();
   }
```

*I'm not sure how you sure about the availability of data , but if you get more than 1 , in FirstOrDefault , you'll have an exception.Oh well..*

Comment: You can also use `SingleOrDefault()` and then check for null instead of using `ToList()` if you know there should only be one value.

Comment: @Royi Namir, thanks for your answer. However I needed to add ".ToString()" to convert the OptionName result to String. Without it i will get the exception unable to cast object to String

Comment: @user3340627 if you refer to my first solution , then yes.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes in your first one